# CSS not loading when used with PathVariable in Spring

Tags: java, html, css, spring

I'm facing issue in CSS loading when used with Spring .Please find below code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view/{id}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewStudentById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("viewStudent");
        model.addObject("studentdata",this.studentService.findStudentById(id));
        return model;
    }
```

But  with value = "/view" CSS of "viewStudent" jsp page is Loaded.Can anyone help me fix this issue ? Why I'm not able to load CSS with (value = "/view/{id}" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by below code.

I was missing / in href .